# div width changes differently in Firefox vs Chrome after resizing viewport

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, flexbox

I noticed a small difference after reducing the viewport with a layout based on flexbox containers. The following snippet contains a few links inside two containers (`.container` and `.subcontainer`). In Chrome (45 beta), the divs with class `element` have the same width regardless of the viewport dimension. However, in Firefox (40), the width of each div changes depending on its content.

```css
   html,
   body {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
   }
   .container {
     position: relative;
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     width: 50%;
   }
   .element {
     flex: 1 0 0;
     padding: 0.5em;
     text-align: center;
     position: relative;
     background-color: red;
     margin-right: 1em;
   }
   .subcontainer {
     flex: 0 1 auto;
     display: flex;
   }
   .element a {
     color: black;
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="subcontainer">
      <div class="element"><a>abc</a>
      </div>
      <div class="element"><a>abcdef</a>
      </div>
      <div class="element"><a>abcdef</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I think the "Run code snippet" functionality doesn't allow to see this change, so I provide a couple of gifs showing the difference:

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

As you can see, the boxes share the same width in Chrome, but Firefox constrains the first box quite noticeably and the other boxes keep their proportions. What is the reason of this discrepancy and how can I fix it? I'd like to have the same width for each box. That was the purpose of using `flex: 1 0 0` in the first place.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, 'does not allow you to see the change'? I have Fx40 and do not see the issue captured in your screenshot when running the snippet.

Comment: Yes. I was referring to the "Run code snippet" feature here in SO (it doesn't allow you to reduce the size of your browser without generating scrollbars) However, if you are using the html snippet in other window, you need to resize your browser quite a bit to see the difference. At some point, Firefox changes the width of each div depending on the content.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try to set `min-width` to any value you need, or just `0px`:

```
.element
{
   ...
   min-width: 0px;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kris48k/2u4h5q0n/2/)

**Details**

For Firefox flex items has `min-width:min-content` by default, as pointed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/min-width)

> These implementations where implementing a slightly simpler behavior
>   for this keyword: it computed to min-content on flex items, and it
>   computes to 0 on everything else.

So, if we set `min-width:-webkit-min-content` for Chrome, it will have the same unwanted behaviour - [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u4h5q0n/3/).

Comment: Interesting. It works. Thank you. Do you know why min-width: 0px; fixes this issue?

Comment: @RobertSmith, I've added details to my answer

Comment: You could write `min-width: 0`, without `px`.

Comment: @SergeyDenisov, yes, I could. But I don't do that, because my style seems to me more readable.

Comment: Thanks. That explains the solution.

Comment: I didn't have the same problem OP had, but this helped me for my spacing issues in Firefox.